# Overwriting function pointer raises error: non-object type is not assignable

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm currently working on a demo to monkey patch c function calls, the idea is that you have a shared c file (eg: `lib.c`), which has one exported function called `void foo()` in the header file `lib.h`.

Currently I'm trying to do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib.h"

void (*foo_original)() = NULL;
void foo_patch()
{    
    puts("Before foo!");
    (*foo_original)();
    puts("Before foo!");
}

int main()
{
    foo_original = &foo;
    foo = &foo_patch;

    // Somewhere else in the code
    foo();
}
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
error: non-object type 'void ()' is not assignable
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
foo = &foo_patch;
```

Is not reassigning the function pointer, but trying to reassign the address of the function `foo` itself, which is not permissible because that's an [r-value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/l-value-and-r-value-expressions).

If you were to reassign the pointer `foo_original` to point to `foo_patch` instead, you'd get an infinite recursion loop because `foo_patch` calls the function pointed to by `foo_original`.

Comment: So essentially what you're saying is it's simply not possible to overwrite the address of `foo()`?

Comment: @paradoxis: that's correct. Functions have fixed addresses in nominally execute-only memory.